# JavaScript Classes Calculator OOP problem

Tags: javascript, class, oop, instance, static-methods

1. Create a `Calculator` class.
2. A newly instantiated instance should have its `total` property initialized to
   `0`.
3. Add the following instance methods which should all return the reassigned
   `total` property of the instance:
   a. `add(num)` - add the `num` arg to the `total`
   b. `subtract(num)` - subtract the `num` arg from the `total`
   c. `divide(num)` - divide the `total` by the `num` arg
   d. `multiply(num)` - multiply the `total` by the `num` arg

```js
let calculator = new Calculator();
console.log(calculator.add(50));      // => 50
console.log(calculator.subtract(35)); // => 15
console.log(calculator.multiply(10)); // => 150
console.log(calculator.divide(5));    // => 30
console.log(calculator.total)         // => 30
```

```
this is what i tried 


class Calculator {
    constructor(total = 0,) {

    this.total = total
    }

    add(num){
        return num + this.total
         
    }
    subtract(num) {
        
        return this.total - num
    }
    divide(num) {
        return this.total / num
    }
    multiply(num) {
        return this.total * num
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: _“methods which should all return the **reassigned** `total` property”_. You never reassign.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are not reassigning the total property of the instance.
You are just returning the result of the operation.

You need to reassign the total property of the instance to the result of the operation.

For example, in the add method, you need to reassign the total property of the instance to the result of the addition operation.

You can do this by using the assignment operator (=) to assign the result of the addition operation to the total property of the instance.
For example, `this.total = num + this.total`. You need to do this for all the methods.

```js
class Calculator {
    constructor(total = 0,) {

    this.total = total
    }

    add(num){
        this.total = num + this.total
        return this.total
         
    }
    subtract(num) {
        this.total = this.total - num
        return this.total
    }
    divide(num) {
        this.total = this.total / num
        return this.total
    }
    multiply(num) {
        this.total = this.total * num
        return this.total
    }
}
```